# Is there a right way to open modal window in wagtail-admin?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I try to improve my wagtail-admin and now I stack because there is no way to open a modal window. Yes, of course, I could create a `div` with a close button, but this would be not the right way. As I've got, there is a special function (or object) which is responsible for opening such a window.

There is no reference for such a structure of js objects of wagtail-admin. May be somebody knows, how to do it? Or maybe I should forget about it and make my modal window just by vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no documented way to use the existing Wagtail admin modals.

However, with a bit of looking at the source code it is possible to leverage the modal workflow to implement your own modals. The approach in Wagtail is to have a server side template response supplied by [`render_modal_workflow`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/modal_workflow.py).

On the client, a function is available [`ModalWorkflow`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/static_src/wagtailadmin/js/modal-workflow.js). That will call a URL async and render the html content inside the modal on response, it expects a response formed by the above `render_modal_workflow` helper.

From these basics it is possible to add open behaviour by a button trigger, error handling, render callbacks and callbacks based on value from inside the modal.

Below is a bare minimum example of a way to render a modal in the admin using this approach.

### Example

#### 1. Render some html content that has a button as a trigger

- For the sake of example, we will render a modal on the Wagtail home (dashboard) page.
- Using the [`construct_homepage_panels`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9/reference/hooks.html#construct-homepage-panels) we can add some html to a panel part way down the page.

**`wagtail_hooks.py`**

```py
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from wagtail.core import hooks

class WelcomePanel:
    order = 110

    def render(self):
        return mark_safe("""
        <section class="panel summary nice-padding">
          <h3>Dashboard Panel Section Title</h3>
          <button data-modal-trigger="some-param">Open Modal</button>
        </section>
        """)

@hooks.register('construct_homepage_panels')
def add_another_welcome_panel(request, panels):
    panels.append(WelcomePanel())
```

#### 2. Ensure the modal-workflow JS script is loaded

- By default, only pages that handle editing have the modal-workflow script loaded
- To add it to this specific page we need to override the [`wagtailadmin/home.html` template](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html) template.
- We will also add a bit of jquery to find any elements that have the `data-modal-trigger` attribute and add an `onClick` listener which will call our `ModalWorkflow` function. This data can be passed back to the modal view, along with any other specific data.

**`templates/wagtailadmin/home.html`**

```html
{% extends "wagtailadmin/home.html" %}
{% load wagtailadmin_tags %}

{% comment %}
    Javascript declaration added to bring in the modal loader, by default it is only available on edit pages
    example of usage - wagtail/search/templates/wagtailsearch/queries/chooser_field.js
{% endcomment %}

{% block extra_js %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <script src="{% versioned_static 'wagtailadmin/js/modal-workflow.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('[data-modal-trigger]').on('click', function(element) {
        /* options passed in 'opts':
          'url' (required): initial
          'responses' (optional): dict of callbacks to be called when the modal content
              calls modal.respond(callbackName, params)
          'onload' (optional): dict of callbacks to be called when loading a step of the workflow.
              The 'step' field in the response identifies the callback to call, passing it the
              modal object and response data as arguments
        */
        ModalWorkflow({
          onError: function(error) { console.log('error', error); },
          url: '/admin/modal/?trigger=' + element.target.dataset.modalTrigger
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

#### 3. Create a view and url to handle the modal requests

- Ensure there is an `admin/...` url that we can request the modal content from
- This url must go to a view that returns a response based on `render_modal_workflow`
- It is possible to initiate data on the client side along with using a normal Django template response for the server side rendered modal content

**`views.py`**

```py
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

from wagtail.admin.modal_workflow import render_modal_workflow


def modal_view(request):

    return render_modal_workflow(
        request,
        'base/modal.html', # html template
        None, # js template
        {'trigger': request.GET.get('trigger')}, # html template vars
        json_data={'some': 'data'} # js template data
    )
```

**`urls.py`**

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import modal_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/modal/', modal_view, name='modal'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    # ...
]
```

#### 4. Set up your template to render the modal content

- Modals all use the same shared header template, which gives a nice way to make it feel consistent.

**`templates/base/modal.html`**

```html
{% include "wagtailadmin/shared/header.html" with title="Modal Title" icon="no-view" %}

<div class="nice-padding">
    <p>Modal Triggered by {{ trigger }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer!